# Why do I have to reload the page, to show the Map correctly?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, jquery

I added a map, in the way I'm supposed to, but why do I have to reload/refresh the page, to get the map (almost) as I want to? This is, what I mean:
Map before reloading the page:
[image: Map before reload]

Map after reloading the page:
[image: Map after reload]

Here is my Code:

```
var map;
    require([
        "esri/map",
        "dojo/dom",
        "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
        "dojo/domReady!"],
        function (Map, dom, Tiled) {
                ....
            var map = new Map("map", {
                logo: false
        });
});
    ...
    var luftbild = new Tiled(URL);
    map.addLayer(luftbild);
```

And this is how I display the map:

```
<div data-role="page" ...>
        <div class="ui-bar-a ui-header">
            ...
            <h1 role="heading" class="ui-title">Karte</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I'm developing with jquery mobile and the ESRI API for JS (in Visual Studio 2013)

**EDIT**

I managed that the map gets displayed well the first time the page has loaded:

[image: Map before reload 2]
I just wrapped the code from above with:

```
$(document).ready(function(/*JS code from above*/));
```

But I still have to reload the page, to display the map as I want to:

[image: Map after reload 2]

How can I force a reload just on this site, ASAP the site is done with loading?

Comment: The map's dom node must be visible before creating it. If the mobile view with the map isn't visible on app load you need to listen for and create the map the first time it becomes visible.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into Dojo Mobile instead because ESRI JSAPI is built on top of that. jQuery mobile may take a bit more work to get working for this purpose. I have not tried it myself, but have had good experiences with Dojo Mobile and ESRI JSAPI.